# Altering UI thread's Views in AsyncTask in doInBackground, CalledFromWrongThreadException not always thrown

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-view

**The following code in an AsycnTask:**

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(View... params) {

try{

    Drawable drawPhoto = DataDatero.ImageDownload(taskPhotoName);
    ((ImageView)params[0]).setImageDrawable(drawPhoto);
    ((TextView)params[1]).setText(taskItemListText);
    ((TextView)params[2]).setTextColor(taskColore);
    ((TextView)params[2]).setText(taskItemStockText);
    [...]
}
```

Throws a CalledFromWrongThreadException , describing that:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views

This has been discussed in plenty of questions: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937399/android-view-viewrootcalledfromwrongthreadexception-only-the-original-thread-t) , another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063408/no-error-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-v) ; and all reach the same conclusion.

**But what I'm not only getting the Exception..**

I call that *execute* from a getView in a List adapter, and the images (params[0]) are updated in the view while the exception is thrown for the text. Also, if I leave only the textview updates , the text is updated and no exception is thrown.

If I update the TextView first and the ImageView after, some text and images are updated while some images are not (that imageDownload includes a 2-3 sec network operation)

**Why some of them are updated and others are not?**

*Notes: this was tested only with sdk 4.0, v4 support, on api 16 emulation.
I fixed it and I'm not touching the views in doInBackground
The second example is something similar... is it that the operation gets validated if onCreate is not finished?*

Answer (score 3):

I have come across a similar issue and asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918912/modifying-views-in-asynctask-doinbackground-does-not-always-throw-exception) (self answered after a good bit of digging).

Essentially what it boils down to is that, contrary to what everybody thinks, you *can* modify UI elements from an `AsyncTask` `execute()` *if* those views haven't gone through a layout traversal yet. This happens asynchronously to the main flow of execution (activity lifecycle methods/callbacks), so if the `View` in question is created shortly before `execute()` is called, you *can* access them (meaning, the exception isn't thrown, it's of course still really bad practice and not advisable). Because `execute()` happens on another thread, the layout traversals (which run on the UI thread) may finish while your `execute()` is running, which explains why only some views may be modified and others throw the exception. It also explains why "leaving only the textview updates" (and presumably removing the `ImageView` updates) results in those updates "magically" working too. Since this is a timing related issue, it depends on many factors, among other things how long `Drawable drawPhoto = DataDatero.ImageDownload(taskPhotoName);` takes to run.

PS: I realise this is a late answer, but I think this can be useful for somebody finding this answer first, there aren't many posts dealing with issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is clear enough. You can not update `UI` element from a thread different from the `UI Thread`. `doInBackground` executes code in a different thread

Comment: yep it's clear enough that's why my question was not a 'how to fix' , the views are altered even there in doinbackground

Comment: doInBackground runs on a a thread different from the thread you use to create the View, tipically the UI Thread

Comment: correct, so my question is 'why am I able to alter the views from another thread' .

Comment: I Run the app and I can see that the fields are populated or empty, im in the chat

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you pass the information to update the UI to the `onPostExecute` method? This is where the UI is intended to be updated.

Comment: i was not asking how to fix, i did that already, i just found it weird that some views are altered regardless that i do it in doInBackground. That's why I included that last note

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `execute` method of your task, the `doInBackground` method is executed in a background thread.

And you are not allowed to modify UI from a background thread.

So, don't modify the UI in the `doInBackground` method.

You should do this UI stuff in `onPostExecute` method instead, which is guaranteed to be executed in UI thread.

Comment: i was not asking how to fix, i did that already, i just found it weird that some views are altered regardless that i do it in doInBackground. That's why I cluded that last note