# Why I am not getting expected CalledFromWrongThreadException when trying to change UI view component from non-ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading

As a beginner in android programming, I am taught that can't change UI view components from non-ui thread, but in the following simple code snippet it seems that it can be done(non ui thread changes button text which is created by UI thread)... I've done research and I should get CalledFromWrongThreadException. Please help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void clickDo(View view){
        MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
        new Thread(myRunnable).start();
    }

    class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            button.setText("newText"); //<-------- here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On button click clickDo() is called which changes button(created by UI thread) text from 'button' to 'newText.'

Comment: What version of the support library are you using? Is your view tag just `<Button`> ?

Comment: When I run your code, I'm getting the expected `CalledFromWrongThreadException` on both API 19 and 28.

Comment: @Ben P. I'm using 28.0.0

Comment: I believe this question is not a duplicate because it involves a delay of (at least) two seconds before changing the text.

Comment: @Ben P. I am not getting CalledFromWrongThreadException ... I will look for reason for that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `TextView.setText()`, a number of things happen. The actual act of modifying the text that's being displayed is a separate action from checking to see if the view's layout needs to be changed, and the *changed layout* is the only thing that needs to be done on the UI thread.

In the source code for `setText()`, there's this little bit:

> ```
> if (mLayout != null) {
>     checkForRelayout();
> }
> ```

Unlike [the previously-linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29918912/8298909), we know that `mLayout` is non-null in this case. So we know that `checkForRelayout()` is being called.

However, looking at `checkForRelayout()` shows that there are certain circumstances where the method returns without ever calling `requestLayout()` and/or `invalidate()`. In these cases (where `requestLayout()` isn't called), the expected `CalledFromWrongThreadException` will not be thrown.

Essentially, if the TextView has a fixed width, and the new text has the same number of lines as the old text, `requestLayout()` won't be called.

That means that you are free to call `setText()` from a non-UI thread as long as you know that the TextView has a fixed width *and* the new and old text have the same number of lines.

---

I did some experimentation to verify this. Indeed, when my `Button` used a `wrap_content` width, I always got the crash with your code. However, when I changed it to `match_parent`, I only got the crash when my new text would wrap to a second line.

Comment: Yes, when I change layout_wirdth of button to wrap_content then I am getting the mentioned exception. Is not it unnatural? Because we are still dealing with non ui thread changing the UI thread created component(button) in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised to learn about this. But I suppose on some level it makes sense; the UI thread is the manager of the view hierarchy, but the view hierarchy isn't actually changing when the text changes (as long as the button size doesn't change). Personally, I'm still going to call UI-related methods from the UI thread.

Comment: @ Ben P.  Thanks for your response! I was looking for to get CalledFromWrongThreadException for learning purpose just to find out why I would need to use handler, AsyncTask  or  your mentioned UI-related methods ... But in this case, in my opinion CalledFromWrongThreadException is not really reasonable exception, I mean it doesn't really justifies its name("...wrongThread"). I think there should have been implemented something new exception which would be thrown  during this particular case...